# rails_admin empregado pode somente editar quem não é administrador

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissões

Rails 5
gens rails_admin, devise, cancancan

Tenho um model User {name:string, ..., admin_role:boolean, employee_role:boolean, user_role:boolean}

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    can :read, :all                 # allow everyone to read everything
    cannot :manage, [Gender]
    return unless user.admin_role? || user.employee_role?
    can :access, :rails_admin       # only allow admin and employee users to access Rails Admin
    can :dashboard, :all            # allow access to dashboard
    if user.admin_role?
      can :manage, :all             # allow superadmins to do anything
    elsif user.employee_role?
      can :update, [User], admin_role: false
    end
  end
end
```

como o "can :update, [User], admin_role: false" consigo "editar" somente os que não são administradores, mas não consigo salvar a edição..

O que estou fazendo errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

troquei o can :update, [User], admin_role: false por can :manage, [User], admin_role: false

Assim fica bem mais completa a regra.